# recursively adding an item to the BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to make a method that will add items to a tree, and then I want to print this tree to the console. I have a class that I inherit and based on it I need to write the methods that I need:

```
public abstract class BinaryTreeNode {
    protected int data; // value stored in the node
    protected BinaryTreeNode left, right; // left and right sub-trees

    // constructor
    public BinaryTreeNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    // recursively adds an item to the BST
    // @param new data to be stored in the new node
    public abstract void addBSTRecursion(int newNode);

    // prints the tree
    // for example, for a tree:
    //        7
    //    6        8
    // 2     7  4     9
    //
    // write:
    //
    //      2
    //   6
    //      7
    // 7
    //      4
    //   8
    //      9

    // method pseudocode
    //if there is a left subtree then print the left one (recursive call)
    //write out gaps (depending on level), write out data, go to new line
    //if it is right, print the right one (recursive call)
    //@param level the distance of the node from the root. We start from 0.
    public abstract void print(int level);

}
```

`addBSTRecursion(int newNode)` -  recursively adds an item to the BST
`print(int level)` - if there is a left subtree then print the left one (recursive call), write out gaps (depending on level), write out data, go to new line, if it is right, print the right one (recursive call)
Here's what I managed to do:

```
public class Node extends BinaryTreeNode {
    public Node(int data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void addBSTRecursion(int newNode) {
        if (data < this.data) {
            if (left != null) {
                left.addBSTRecursion(newNode);
            } else {
                left = new Node(newNode);
            }
        } else {
            if (right != null) {
                right.addBSTRecursion(newNode);
            } else {
                right = new Node(newNode);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void print(int level) {
        if(this.left != null)this.left.print(level+1);
        for(int n =0; n<level; n++) System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println(data);
        if(this.right != null)this.right.print(level+1);
    }
}
```

My output:

```
10
 5
  14
```

I would like to receive:

```
   5
10
   14
```

Comment: If your nodes are going to have an int ID. Than Ideally with a binary tree. You would want the root node to always to have a value in the middle of all subsequent child nodes. So any node on the left should always have a lower value, and nodes on the right should always have a higher value. Not matter what level any two give nodes are at..  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt2yBZAhsGM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always going to be `false`, since it compares `this.data` with itself:

```
    if (data < this.data) {
```

It should be:

```
    if (newNode < this.data) {
```

NB: calling the parameter `newNode` is misleading, as it is not a `Node` type, but an integer. Maybe call it `newData`.

Comment: better late than never :)