# the BST search method ((iteratively)) returning the node containing the searched value and its predecessor

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Okay, I've already written several methods related to my problem. Right now I have two methods that are written using recursion (`addBSTRecursion (int element)` and `searchBSTRecursion (int element)`). And now I need implement (iteratively) the BST search method (`Pair<BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST(int element)`) returning the node containing the searched value and its predecessor.

- if the searched element is not in the tree, the first element of the pair is `null`.
- if the first element of the pair is a root (it has no predecessor), then the second element of the pair is `null`.
  Here is my class Pair:

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> {
    public T1 first;
    public T2 second;

    public Pair(T1 a, T2 b) {
        first = a;
        second = b;
    }
}
```

This is how I managed to implement method (`Pair<BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST(int element)`), but unfortunately it does not work as expected.

```
@Override
public Pair<BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST(int element) {
    int current = 0;
    while (element != data) {
        if (element < data) {
            current = left.data;
        } else {
            current = right.data;
        }
    }
    Pair pair = new Pair(element, current);
    return pair;
}
```

To be honest, I don’t know yet how to correctly implement this method, I will be glad to any hints. And also at the bottom I add all my previous classes.

```
public abstract class BinaryTreeNode {
    protected int data; // value stored in the node
    protected BinaryTreeNode left, right; // left and right sub-trees

    // constructor
    public BinaryTreeNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    // recursively adds an item to the BST
    // @param new data to be stored in the new node
    public abstract void addBSTRecursion(int element);

    // prints the tree
    // for example, for a tree:
    //        7
    //    6        8
    // 2     7  4     9
    //
    // write:
    //
    //      2
    //   6
    //      7
    // 7
    //      4
    //   8
    //      9

    // method pseudocode
    // if there is a left subtree then print the left one (recursive call)
    // write out gaps (depending on level), write out data, go to new line
    // if it is right, print the right one (recursive call)
    // @param level the distance of the node from the root. We start from 0.
    public abstract void print(int level);

    // recursive searches the BST.
    // returns true if it finds an element with the given value
    // @param searched value searched
    // @return true if the given value is in the tree, false otherwise
    public abstract boolean searchBSTRecursion(int element);

    // iterative lookup of values in the BST
    // returns a pair: node containing the searched element and its predecessor.
    // if the searched element is not in the tree, the first element of the pair is null.
    // if the first element of the pair is a root (it has no predecessor), then the second element of the pair is null.
    // @param searched value searched
    // @return pair of nodes: the first is the node containing the value searched for, or null if not found;
    // the second element of the pair is the parent of the node (or null if the value is at the root of the tree)
    public abstract Pair < BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode > searchBST(int element);
}
```

```
public class Node extends BinaryTreeNode {
    public Node(int data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void addBSTRecursion(int element) {
        Node node = new Node(element);
        if (element < data) {
            if (left != null) {
                left.addBSTRecursion(element);
            } else {
                left = node;
            }
        } else {
            if (right != null) {
                right.addBSTRecursion(element);
            } else {
                right = node;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void print(int level) {
        if (left != null) {
            left.print(level + 4);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.print(data + "\n");

        if (right != null) {
            right.print(level + 4);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean searchBSTRecursion(int element) {
        if (element == data) {
            return true;
        } else if (element < data) {
            if (left != null && left.searchBSTRecursion(element)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (right != null && right.searchBSTRecursion(element)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Pair<BinaryTreeNode, BinaryTreeNode> searchBST(int element) {
        int current = 0;
        while (element != data) {
            if (element < data) {
                current = left.data;
            } else {
                current = right.data;
            }
        }
        Pair pair = new Pair(element, current);
        return pair;
    }

}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node = new Node(8);

        node.addBSTRecursion(3);
        node.addBSTRecursion(10);

        node.addBSTRecursion(1);
        node.addBSTRecursion(6);

        node.addBSTRecursion(14);

        node.addBSTRecursion(4);
        node.addBSTRecursion(7);

        node.addBSTRecursion(13);


        node.print(0);

        System.out.print(node.searchBSTRecursion(15));
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe first give feed-back on the answer(s) you got on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319261/recursively-adding-an-item-to-the-bst)? -- it seems you have used that answer but did not mark it as accepted?

Comment: Your new function is using different property names. They seem to use Polish names, while the rest of your code is using English property names. Can you harmonise this and preferably using English terms?